# How can you use Windows 7 Classic theme on non-Windows installations?

Tags: eclipse

Installing Eclipse on Windows 7 with the primary Eclipse bundle comes with 2 windows 7 themes including a Windows 7 classic.

But installing on Linux didn't come with these themes. How can you get those themes on Linux?

Comment: Since Eclipse uses [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), the themes available are likely based on the operating system's rendering components.

Comment: Although that's a good point, there are a number of reasons to doubt this. 1) the Windows version also comes with a regular "Classic" theme. This same theme comes in the Linux package as well, and this theme looks the exact same on Linux as it does on Windows. 2) The Windows package also comes with "Window XP Blue" and Olive themes, and I know for a fact I'm not running Windows XP and Windows 7 on the same machine at the same time, so these are probably just names with no other significance. 3) "Classic" and Windows 7 Classic" look very similar with mostly just color shades & icon differences

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. They are only included with the Windows package, because it is being installed on the same platform as the themes.

Sorry